# Accessing Stored Jenkins credentials from Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i am trying to trigger a google cli command in jenkins pipeline.

**gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=user.json**

currently using googlesdk docker image

Here i have my private key stored as credentials in Jenkins server while running command directly from agent i can authenticate to the account. now i wanted to run command inside docker container.

need to know how can i access private key stored in Jenkins from Docker container ?

i tried to access it directly and got following error message

> ERROR: gcloud crashed (ValueError): No key could be detected.

some Assistance will be helpful.

i use scripted pipeline.

Comment: You can checkout the credentials keyfile and pass it to your docker container. Adding your jenkinsfile will be better.

Comment: Thanks @vijay
Using *withCredentials* canbe used for accessing credentials stored in jenkins inside Container as shown in below example eg:
 `withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'players_key', variable: 'key')]) {
    withDockerContainer(image: "python_img", args: "-e id_key='${key}'") {
            sh "python -u ./pipeline/abc.py"
    }`